# Google Storage JSON API Uploading file with .Net core

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have trouble uploading a file to Google cloud bucket. It is an audio file. If I convert the file contents to base64, upload succeeds. But on cloud bucket side, there is nothing to convert it back to binary audio file. It does not happen automatically. 
If I write binary bytes to the request stream, it times out.

I need to be on .Net core 2.0 and make it work with Unity3D. Hence can not use client library which is meant for .Net higher framework versions.

```
 string fileName = Path.GetFileName(strAudioFileName);
 HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/my-bucket/o?uploadType=media&name=" + fileName );
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Headers["x-goog-project-id"] = "9999999999";

    byte[] bFileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(strAudioFileName);
    //string strFileContent = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(strAudioFileName));// upload works if i use this.
    Debug.Log("File size: Binary Length" + bFileContent.Length);

    request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    request.ContentLength = bFileContent.Length;
    //request.ContentLength =strFileContent.Length; //Length if base64 is used.
    if (m_Token != null)
    {
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + m_Token;
    }

    StreamWriter RestReqstreamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
    RestReqstreamWriter.Write(File.ReadAllBytes(strAudioFileName));
    RestReqstreamWriter.Flush();
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Questions: 
1. With base64 encoding, is there any request content type I could try which will automatically convert to binary?

2. For making it with with binary file upload without base64, is there any way? My code here is timing out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Your code is reading the file twice. 2) How big is the file? 3) If you base64 encode a file, there is nothing in Cloud Storage to automatically decode it. The file will stay base64 encoded.

Comment: Thanks for the response. File is just 48 kB. With base64, it becoms about 64 kB. I thought the first readallbytes should not matter since I do not process it furether. Also after removing it did not make difference. But I am suspecting RestReqstreamWriter.Write(File.ReadAllBytes(strAudioFileName)); The Write() function takes char while I need it to take byte. I did not find any alternative..

Comment: As I mentioned, the issue appears to be coming from the mismatch of request.ContentLength = bFileContent.Length;  and RestReqstreamWriter.Write(File.ReadAllBytes(strAudioFileName)).  Write () takes 'Char' and bFileContent.Length shows number of bytes... Please suggest if this is correct analysis. Request either times out or returns error that 'more bytes to be written' - depending upon the code tweaks I tired..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this.
     StreamWriter RestReqstreamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())

Instead of StreamWriter, I used Stream class. It has Write function with byte[] as param.

It worked for me.